# Upload byte array to blob storage with other object C#

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload byte array to Azure blog storage.

i am sending below data to WebApi with byte array property

```
{
'FirstName':'Satish',
'LastName':'Kumar',
'Email':'satish@gmail.com',
'Password':'satish',
'UploadImage':byte[23232]
}
```

i am sending the above object through the Javascript Ajax post request to my Web Api, and i am able to get the collection on server successfully but when i am trying to upload the byte array to azure storage, the size of image uploaded is only 1 kb.

Below is the code to upload on blob storage

```
CloudManager cloudManager = new CloudManager();
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(UploadImage);

string imageKey = string.Empty;
imageKey = string.Format("{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());
user.ImageName = cloudManager.UploadBlob(imageKey, stream);
```

Please help me to know what is wrong

Comment: Try resetting the stream's position by doing something like `stream.Position = 0;`. HTH.

Comment: There are two transmissions involved here. browser->your server, and then from your server->Azure storage. Which part has the problem? i.e., can you tell if the data made it through from the browser to your server, and the problem is with the upload? Also, the "CloudManager" class you are using - which dll/namespace is that in?